# Is it OK? clearOverlays() in GMap API V2 to Google Maps API V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Maps API V3.

I migrate My site GMap API V2 -> V3.
 but coped because I used the clearOverlays() method to delete an existing object at once in the V2 , and it deleted an object in what had been abolished in V3 individually.

**V2**

```js
map.clearOverlays();
```

**V3**

```js
map.set_visible(false);
popup.close();
```

is it OK? 
or other solutions?

Comment: I wrote a quick blog about it and put some sample code up as well
http://www.joelee.me.uk/2010/07/27/clearoverlays-in-google-maps-v3-api/

Comment: Just look at this example that is in the Google docs: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-remove.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the [V3 reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html) which will explicitly clear the overlays created on the map and I could't find any code samples which do this either.

I think that it is important to point out the V3 API is a very early developer release and contains only a *very basic* set of features.  It is quite possible that they simply haven't got to this functionality yet. If you are working on a  live system, I suggest you stick with V2 until V3 is more mature.

There is a post on the developer group which asks the question about how the API should be used with a very useful answer from the V3 product manager:

[Misconception about v3 Options](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/ea02ee8291d3577e)

EDIT:

OK, it seems like this functionality is missing from the API deliberately in order to keep it lightweight.  You should keep track of your overlay objects yourself and call:

```js
object.set_map(null);
```

to remove them.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I do:

create an empty array literal, push the markers as you make them, and then evict them when necessary

```js
var eviction_list = [];

function evictMarkers() {

    // clear all markers

    $(eviction_list).each(function () {
         this.set_map(null);
    });

    // reset the eviction array 
    eviction_list = [];
}

//in function adding markers
......
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    map: map,
    title: elem.title
});
eviction_list.push(marker);
......

//to clear all markers
evictMarkers();
```

Comment: I'm using a similar approach on a mapping project, and it works well. The only major change is to use setMap() in place of set_map().

Comment: if you're not using jquery: `markers.forEach(function(item) { item.setMap(null) });`

Answer (score 3):

As hongwei correctly mentions, the function is called setMap(), not set_map().

See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/overlays.html#HideShow

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `setMap(null)` can be slow when you have many markers.