# JavaScript: set_map not working anymore

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was using built-in JavaScript `.set_map` function as discussed on [this stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers) but not, it just stopped working.

I've literally not changed my code in 2 months and now, Firebug is reporting:

Error: *set_map is not a function*

It appears the original poster of the Google Maps plugin is also experiencing the issue on his/her demo site when you click the "clear" button.

www.lootogo.com/googlemapsapi3/markerPlugin.html

Any ideas why the "set_map" function no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google changed their API.

`set_map` is now `setMap`

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html

Comment: I cant accept my own answer for 2 days ... but this is the answer

Comment: APIs in Google Labs status can, and do, change their syntax with relatively little warning. If you use a Google Labs API, then you really should keep an eye on the associated discussion group. 

For stable APIs, like Maps v2, Google try to give backwards compatibility, so that pages can continue to use the old syntax, or give three years notice of any page-breaking changes if that's not possible.