# Google Maps API v3 - How to clear overlays?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps API v2, I was using `map.clearOverlays()` to remove the marker and draw them again.

How can I do that using Google Maps API v3 ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3: How to remove all markers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers)

Comment: Indeed since it is the post linked to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers) for details on the various options open to you but you now have to iterate through the markers and remove them individually. Your code should look something like this:

```
var markers = [];

function clearOverlays() {
 while(markers.length) { markers.pop().setMap(null); }
  markers.length = 0;
}

markers.push(marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){});
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged for removal because it is a link-only answer. Could you please expand this answer so it provides an answer to the question without requiring the reader to click to the linked webpage?

Answer (score 35):

This is good one:

http://apitricks.blogspot.com/2010/02/clearoverlays-in-v3.html

Article in case the link dies:

`clearOverlays() in V3`

There is no clearOverlays() in API v3. Some practices have been presented. I think this is the simpliest so far.

Push all the overlays in an array when created (as usual). Following code will clear both map and the array:

```
while(overlays[0])
{
  overlays.pop().setMap(null);
}
```

pop() method of an array removes the last element of an array, and returns that element. 'while' keeps that happening as long as there are elements in the array. When overlays[0] does not exist anymore, the mission is completed and code will proceed.

Comment: VERY GOOD SOLUTION!  i had problems implementing your function until i saved the pop()èd polyline into a temp object first:  
var arrayTemp = overlayArrayPolylineUpload.pop(); arrayTemp.setMap(null);

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution and it works very good 
it will remove all overlays that exist on the map

```
gmap.overlayMapTypes.setAt( 0, null);
```

while gmap is your map object

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Google Maps documentation as it show simple deleteOverLays method http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html

```
// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: removing from map is HIDING, not DELETING.  the markers still exist, but you got rid of the array that held them.  you must setMap(null) then set the marker itself to null.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#RemovingOverlays

Answer (score 1):

The `overlayMapTypes` object brings a clear method:

`map.overlayMapTypes.clear()`

Whereas map is your Google Maps object.

If you cannot find the method in your API version, you can resort to the following source of `clear`:

```
clear = function() {
    for (; this.get("length");) this.pop()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example provided by Google here:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/clear-all-overlays/clear-all-overlays.html

Basically the idea is the remove

- Markers
- Polygons
- and Polylines separately

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? I don't want to use the .setMap(null), because I don't know a better way to initiate the polyShape again.

```
polyShape = new google.maps.Polygon(
    {
        strokeColor     : '#000000',
        strokeOpacity   : 0.3,
        strokeWeight    : 1,
        fillColor       : "#000000",
        fillOpacity     : 0.26,
        geodesic        : true
    });
```

Then.. iterate through the path to remove it.

```
var path = new google.maps.MVCArray;

/**
 * Delete all points inside Map
 */
function clearMap()
{
    //clear markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    {
        markers[i].setMap(null);

    }
    markers = [];

    //clear polygon, still finding more elegant way
    while (polyShape.getPath().length)
    {
        path.removeAt(0);
    }
}
```