# Remove all features from data layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used something like:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137.883}
  });
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

to load a geojson shape file to the map.data layer of my map. In the shape file, there are a couple of 'feature' classes defining polygons to be drawn on the map. Up until here I have no problems.

Later on though, I want to load another geojson file over the other one (replacing the drawn 'features' on the map). When you just load another file over the other one it  just redraws it over the other one. How on earth do you clear the map.data layer of all the features before loading in the new geojson shape file?

I've tried using
    `map.data.remove(feature)`
with a loop, but I can't seem to get all the features from the map.data layer.

Comment: Maybe [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948097/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-clear-overlays#answer-7882263) will be useful to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, markers are in a different layer to the map.data layer. But already found the solution thanks. Plus the final solution is for google maps api v2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will iterate over all the features and remove them from **map.data**.

```
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    // If you want, check here for some constraints.
    map.data.remove(feature);
});
```

**Edit 1: Explanation**
Map data forEach function use callbacks, so you have to give a callback function as parameter:

```
var callback = function(){ alert("Hi, I am a callback"); }; 
map.data.forEach(callback);
```

Now for each element in data it will show an alert. It's also possible to give callbacks with parameter, like in the code shown above.

```
   var callback = function(feature) {
        // If you want, check here for some constraints.
        map.data.remove(feature);
   };
   map.data.forEach(callback);
```

Further explanation and examples: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: I tried `map.data.forEach(map.data.remove)` but it threw an error.  Shouldn't it do the same thing as what you wrote?

Comment: You tried my code or only `map.data.forEach(map.data.remove)` ?

Comment: I tried both.  Your way works fine.  Mine does not.  I guess I don't understand javascript well enough to take shortcuts like this.

Comment: Yes, its tricky how the anonymus function works. I can't explain it either. Maybe this [link](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) helps you, to understand the concept of a callback a little bite more.

Comment: map.data.forEach(map.data.remove.bind(this)) might work. :)

Comment: I've tried to use it to remove the manually added polygons and markers. This loop does not find either of them.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the `map.data` is a collection of 'feature' classes.

So you can use the map.data to iterate through and remove each feature in the collection