# google maps v3 setMap undefined when trying to clear all markers

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have seen may people here explain this function:

```
// REMOVE All MARKERS FUNCTION
    // Removes all markers currently on map
    // PARAMS: None
    function removeAllMarkers(){// removes all markers from map
        if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
                markersArray = [];
                markersInfoArray = [];
            };
        };
    };
```

but i get a javascript error...

Break on Error
markersArray[i].setMap is not a function

The page is at: http://www.focus-on-plants.com/locator.php

any ideas???

<---------------Update--------------------->

i tried the sugestions and also moved the `MarkersArray=[]` and `markersInfoArray = []` to out side of the for loop so i had this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ){
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
}
```

But i get the same `error markersArray[i].setMap is not a function`

so i looked around and tried this method:

```
function removeAllMarkers(){// removes all markers from map
    alert('REMOVE MARKERS - markersArray count:'+ markersArray.length);
    while(markersArray[0]){
        markersArray.pop().setMap(null);
        markersInfoArray.pop()
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
    markersInfoArray.length = 0;
};
```

and i still get the same error, what gives? its almost as though the setMap() does not exist, i read in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers) that it change from set_map to setMap() but those dont work for me either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so ive got it to work, the soloution is kind of ugly but it works,

i figured it wasnt finding the google.maps namespace bit from stored markers in my array  so thats why it thought the function dosen't exist.

ie. it should be `google.maps.marker.setMap()` the marker in the array was just outputting the lat and lng.

so within the removeAllMarkers function i create a new google.maps.marker `delmarker`
populate it with the data from the marker stored in the `markersArray`
and then remove the marker of the map using this new reference `delmarker.setMap(null)`

and bingo it works, but longwinded and took me a while to figure out :)

```
function removeAllMarkers(){// removes all markers from map
    for( var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ){
    delmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markersArray[i]
    })
    delmarker.setMap(null)
    }   
    markersArray.length = 0;
    markersInfoArray.length = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same issue as you. But changing the for-in loop to an actual loop (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays), fixed it.

There was no need to create a new google.maps.marker when removing the marker.

Sample code:

```
var markersArray = [];
```

function addMarker() {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map 
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
}

function removeMarker() {
    if (markersArray) {
        for (i=0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
    markersArray.length = 0;
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Try an actual loop. `for (i in markersArray)` will also retrieve properties. It's not the same as, say, PHP's `foreach`.

```
for( var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {}
```

Comment: that works nicely thanks, i give you both correct answers!! Harmen for spotting the markersArray =[] in the for loop and you for this thanks peoples!!

Comment: see comment in above answer :(

Answer (score 2):

It breaks because you reset the array inside the loop. This might be a lot better:

```
function removeAllMarkers(){
    if (markersArray) {
        for (i in markersArray) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }

        markersArray = [];
        markersInfoArray = [];
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need to use a `;` *all* the time ;)

Comment: thanks tired eyes didn't spot that, i thought it was good practice to use the ; i have just got used to doing it i guess

Comment: Haha, often it's good use to add a semicolon, but the docs say that you need to add it only after a statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements — anyway, Javascript is not like PHP, you don't always get an error if you forget a semicolon

Comment: hmmm thought it was fixed but still getting the same error, ir alerts that there are markers but still comes up with makersArray[i]setMap() is not a function