# Loading googlemaps on page load

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Hi iam trying to load googlemaps when the new page is loaded ..but itz not working below is my code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var query = location.href.substring((location.href.indexOf('?')+1), location.href.length);
    if(location.href.indexOf('?') < 0) query = '';
    querysplit = query.split('&');
    query = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < querysplit.length; i++){
    var namevalue = querysplit[i].split('=');
    namevalue[1] = namevalue[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    query[namevalue[0]] = unescape(namevalue[1]);
    }
    window.onload = function(lat,lng){
    // Do stuff with query string data here.
alert(query['latitute']);
    var map;
    //code write to load map on right side
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        center: myLatlng,
                        zoom: 10});
    }
    </script>
```

my goal is when i click link on firstpage the second page should load with the map taking the latlng from firstpage which are hardcoded..the alert statement is wrking but not the map load..trying to implement it in jquery or js..Any help is appreciated

Comment: is that all the HTML that's on the page?
you are missing an element with ID 'map' then, as is used in document.getElementById('map') ...

Comment: no i have the id in the html page as follows :<div id="map" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:800px;">
Map will load here</div>

Comment: can u suggest how to load using jquery? with js the map is not loading at all

Comment: Spelling the way you do it's no surprise that your code doesn't work. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you receive **lat** and **lng** values? Have you tried show alert with this variables?

Also, if your first alert works, try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var lat = parseFloat(query['latitute']);
    var lng = parseFloat(query['longitute']);
    var map;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 10
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: hi..the alert statement is working..but map is not loading..but i could see the zoom controls but not map

Comment: what happens if you zoom out? do you still see nothing or does it show a location on earth? because if it show some location, your coordinates are just incorrect...

Comment: yes i checked the coordinates ..they are correct..but map is not loading except zoom controls

Comment: Maybe your map is not resizing. Try `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` at end of `onload`.

Comment: @HareshVeldurty What you have with `alert(myLatlng)`?

Comment: So, that's the problem, you don't have correct coordinates passing to `google.maps.LatLng()` function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17508/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-haresh-veldurty)

Comment: final answer as suggested by Paulo Rodrigues : var lat = parseFloat(query['latitude']);
var lng = parseFloat(query['longitude']);

Comment: Hi ..anyidea for this query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721287/settimeout-to-avoid-over-query-limit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do something like this:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktothis.html?lat=42.359783&lng=-71.092800&zoom=14&type=h

(it parses the query string and centers the map at the coordinates obtained)
But modifying the "lat" to be "latitude" and "lng" to be longitude