# Settimeout to avoid over_query-limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

i am trying to retrieve addresses using the googlemaps geocoder..but iam getting only few addresses ..as i see my javascript is failing to retrieve after 10 addresses..below is my code

```
function fetchData(lat,lng,type){   

    $('#placedata').empty();
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 10});
    var request = {location: myLatlng,radius: 50000,types: [type]};
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {  

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {  
          createMarker(results[i]);     
        }       
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    place.geometry.location});

    var request = {reference: place.reference,};
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.getDetails(request, detailsDisplay);

    function detailsDisplay(details, status) {      
        $('#placedata').append('<tr><td><a href='+details.url+'>'+details.name+'</a></td></tr>');

    }

}
```

As i see many have same problem ..is there a way or  using setTimeout function and delay the request so i get get atleast 20 addresses..Any help would be appreciated..thankyou

Comment: `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` is when webpage has gone over its request quota, 25.000 according the Maps API Library. Maybe some error happens when you get this tenth record. Did you check the `status` in `callback()` function?

Comment: the alert statement is giving all the 20 results..how to check the status

Comment: the akert(ok); when i repeatedly click tht iam getting 20 results

Comment: ok, but where is this alert? to check if everything it's ok, you need check if all 20 `status` in callback return `google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK`.

Comment: iam sorry i did not get you...getting the 20 results but unable to diaplay on the first run...i could only display 10

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17553/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-haresh-veldurty)

Comment: hey u there?..can u come to online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is use `setTimeout` to prevent `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`:

```
function createMarker(place) {
    //var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,zIndex: 100,position: place.geometry.location});

    var request = {
        reference : place.reference,
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            $('#placedata').append('<tr><td><a href='+details.url+'>' + details.name + '</a></td></tr>');
        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                createMarker(place);
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi..if have a problem if the results are more than 20..samething i can get the results but unable to display more than 20

Comment: Hi..there is problem displaying all the results ..getting 60 results but able to display only 20 resuts with the above timeout function.

Answer (score -1):

I have the solution for this.

try this

```
if(pagination.hasNextPage){
pagination.nextPage();
}

if(pagination.b == null){
createMarker(place);
}
```

//No need for setTimeout. try this. it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Care to explain what the heck pagination is and where you got this variable? The original post and none since it mention it.

Comment: pagination is a callback function in Google Map Places service Api 

service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status, pagination) {