# Google Maps V3 Remove all markers after each click

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

At the moment when my `.preview` button is clicked it looks at each address in a `textarea` and then plots it.

I would like to remove the markers each time `.preview` is clicked as I see that it just plots another marker around the same point as the marker before.

```
$('.preview').click(function(){    
setAllMap(null);
var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("gps").value.split("\n");
    for(var i=0;i<temp_addresses.length;i++){
        addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': temp_addresses[i]}, function(response, status) {
            geocode_results[i] = new Array();
            geocode_results[i]['status'] = status;
            var top_location = response[0];
            var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000)/1000000;
            var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000)/1000000;
            geocode_results[i]['lat'] = lat;
            geocode_results[i]['lng'] = lng;
            geocode_results[i]['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;
            marker = markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: mapIcon,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                map: map
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This gives me a console.log() of `ReferenceError: setAllMap is not defined`

I have tried `marker.setMap(null);` but I get back `TypeError: marker.setMap is not a function`

Help is appreciated

Edit.

```
    var marker = [];

    var addresses = new Array();
    var geocode_results = new Array();
    function setAllMap(map) {
       for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
          marker[i].setMap(map);
       }
    }
    $('.preview').click(function(){    
setAllMap(null);
var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("gps").value.split("\n");
    for(var i=0;i<temp_addresses.length;i++){
        addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': temp_addresses[i]}, function(response, status) {
            geocode_results[i] = new Array();
            geocode_results[i]['status'] = status;
            var top_location = response[0];
            var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000)/1000000;
            var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000)/1000000;
            geocode_results[i]['lat'] = lat;
            geocode_results[i]['lng'] = lng;
            geocode_results[i]['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;
            marker = markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: mapIcon,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                map: map
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Means, you want to clear the all the marker on map ....

Comment: @ManetiVinay just as long as the markers are gone and will be replotted according to the `var temp_addresses`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove    I think this links is use full..........

Comment: @ManetiVinay I seen this and it does not seem to remove the markers. It outputs the errors I posted originally

Comment: Where is the `setAllMap` function at, and what does it look like?  Where did you call `marker.setMap(null);`?  Your question hasn't got enough detail in it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137308/google-maps-v3-setmap-undefined-when-trying-to-clear-all-markers      You may get some information before this was ans...

Comment: Placed `marker.setMap(null);` after `$('.preview').click(function(){` I done the same with `satAllMap` too and this still comes up with error `ReferenceError: setAllMap is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a setAllMap function (it isn't part of the API)...  if the markers array is in the global scope, this should work.

```
function setAllMap(map) {
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
   }
}
```

or you can just put the loop where you call the function.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work, there are no errors but the markers still stay in position. See edit

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle that shows the problem? It should work if the markers array is global, but I didn't test it (as you didn't provide enough code to do so easily...)