# Refreshing Google Map is preventing ability to add markers

Tags: javascript, function

I have problem with after 'refreshing' my Google Map, I am not able to place in marker by myself(Clicking). But before refreshing my map(With the initialize one), I am able to place marker in by clicking. May I know what's wrong with the code?

Below are my codes...

```
//Initialize the map
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(2,110);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading..."
    });
}

// Listen for click for markers
function marker()
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

// Place markers in by click

function addMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        title:"Specified Location",
        icon: 'images/greenPoint.png'
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
}


function refreshMap()
{
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.1,107);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a new google.maps.Map object in the first place?  You should do something like this instead:

```
function refreshMap()
{
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.1,107);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
    };
    map.setOptions(myOptions);
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, perhaps I didn't make my questions sounds more clearer. For example, after I have initialized my map, I placed some markers down. After that, I press the refreshMap() button (This will allow me to CLEAR all the markers) and then after I press the marker() function again, I will be able to place markers down again... Because for what I did now, after I have refresh my map, when I press the function to add marker, I couldn't add any at all.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are saying that your map doesn't work after you call the `refreshMap` function.  Sounds to me like a scoping issue, where the `map` variable is in a different scope the second time.  Try putting this line:

```
var map = null;
```

at the very top of the file, to be sure that all of the `map` references are to the same global `map` variable.

Comment: Hi Colin, But I have already put a var map; on top as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `markersArray` you should be able to clear the map using the approach from here: [Google Maps API v3: How to remove all markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers)

```
function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}
```