# Placing a marker in Google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So I am preparing a page which has a Google Map and there are two forms namely latitude and longitude , and a submit button.

On entering the longitude and latitude the map is centered to the desired location and puts a marker there.

The problem I am facing is that whenever I put a new lat/long , the old marker won't go.
So basically if entered first lat/long : 10/12 , it would center to that and place a marker there, but when i enter the second lat/long (say) : 11/12 , it would center to that too and place a marker there also while the first one is not removed.

I want the page to be whenever the a new entered in the form only that one reflects in the form no old markers.

Here's my CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.6667,76.2667),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function pan() {
        var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value, document.getElementById("lng").value);
        map.setCenter(panPoint)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: panPoint,
            });

     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 Latitude:<input type="text" id="lat" >
 Longitude:<input type="text" id="lng">
 <input type="button" value="updateCenter" onclick="pan()" />


 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Some help would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
 }
</style>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
   var map;
  var markersArray=[];
   function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.6667,76.2667),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function pan() {
deleteOverlays();
    var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value,     document.getElementById("lng").value);
    map.setCenter(panPoint)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: panPoint,
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);

 }

 function deleteOverlays() {
   if (markersArray) {
      for (i in markersArray) {
       markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Latitude:<input type="text" id="lat" >
Longitude:<input type="text" id="lng">
<input type="button" value="updateCenter" onclick="pan()" />


<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear markers each time in order to do that. 
To clean marker keep marker as global variable, eg.

```
function pan() {
    try{
        marker.setMap(null);//clear marker
     }
     catch(err){
     }

    var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value, document.getElementById("lng").value);
    map.setCenter(panPoint)
    //declare marker as global variable
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: panPoint,
        });

 }
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the pan function before adding the new marker, try to remove all the present markers [Google Maps API v3: How to remove all markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers)