# Marker is not removing from mapV2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am adding a maker on touch of map and want to remove that marker on click of some button but that marker is not removing from map .Here is my Code

```
    // Marker of end Point
Marker endPointMarker;
```

onclick of map

```
        @Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double lat = point.latitude;
    double lng = point.longitude;

    // Add marker of destination point

            try {
                Geocoder geocoder;
                List<Address> addresses;
                geocoder = new Geocoder(BookCabScreen.this);
                if (lat != 0 || lng != 0) {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                    String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                    Log.d("TAG", "address = " + address + ", city =" + city
                            + ", country = " + country);
                    endPointMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                            .title("Location").snippet("" + address));

                    markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                            .title("Location").snippet("" + address)));
                    btnStartUp.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStopPoint.setEnabled(true);

                    mJbBookCab.setEndPointLat(lat);
                    mJbBookCab.setEndPointLng(lng);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BookCabScreen.this,
                            "latitude and longitude are null",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


}
```

on click of button

```
            if (endPointMarker != null) {
            endPointMarker.remove();

            endPointMarker = null;
        }
```

But it is not removing from map ?Please help

Comment: Try looking at this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482949/google-map-api-removing-markers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding same marker twice:

```
                endPointMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                        .title("Location").snippet("" + address));

                markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                        .title("Location").snippet("" + address)));
```

Just remove one call to `GoogleMap.addMarker`.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is correct but if this is not working then You can use mMap.clear() inside your onclick method this will remove all the markers or if you want only a specific marker not to be shown then you can use endPointMarker.setVisible(false)

Comment: I can't use clear method because there are some other markers also.I also use setvisible(false) but there is same result