# Issue when changing icon in android maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-maps-v2

I'm having a strange behavior with my markers in android maps v2.

I have a method that change the marker's icon for another when I click on a dialog button.

When the method ends, the icon changes but the old icon are still on the map.

I have noticed that when I changed the marker's shape. Here are some images to helping you understand

I tried calling remove() and adding the marker again, but no luck =(

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QLFm.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pekOM.png)

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet of what you already have/did?

Answer (score 0):

May this could `Marker.setVisible(boolean)` work or

you could check this also [Remove previous Marker and add new Marker in Google Map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379807/remove-previous-marker-and-add-new-marker-in-google-map-v2)

Comment: I tried both methods but no luck. And else, I have a custom marker click listener, that isn't called anymore when removing and adding a new marker.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what happened. I call a method that add the markers twice. This answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538278/marker-is-not-removing-from-mapv2-android