# how to remove markers with mysql data from Google Maps v3 API?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, codeigniter-3

I've just followed the steps on this link: [Google Map API - Removing Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482949/google-map-api-removing-markers)

I created a search function with google maps v3 api to display a markers and when a marker clicked, it will show the resident data and its direction data. The problem is i can't remove the previous loaded markers that i searched.

Any suggestions, ideas and help will much appreciated!

**JS Code:**

```
$("#searchDataToMarker").on('keydown', function() {
document.getElementById('directionsDiv').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('residentInfoDiv').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('dataTitle').innerHTML = "";
var value = $(this).val();
var marker;
var markers = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.origin + "/Map/mapSearchDataInMarker",
    data: {
        'searchDataToMarker': value
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(searchMapDataResults) {
        clearMarkers();
        removeMarkers();
        deleteMarkers();
        if (searchMapDataResults.length === 0 || $("#searchDataToMarker").val() === null) {
            document.getElementById('directionsDiv').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('residentInfoDiv').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('dataTitle').innerHTML = "";
            // google.maps.trigger(map, 'resize');
            $.bootstrapGrowl("<h4><strong>Resident not found!</strong></h4> <p>Search result empty!</p>", {
                type: "warning",
                delay: 2500,
                width: "auto",
                allow_dismiss: true,
                offset: {
                    from: 'top',
                    amount: 20
                }
            });
            return;
        } else {
            clearMarkers();
            removeMarkers();
            deleteMarkers();
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                suppressMarkers: true
            });
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(7.285764, 125.680568);
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
                $(this.getDiv()).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
            });
            for (var i = 0, length = searchMapDataResults.length; i < length; i++) {
                var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var data = searchMapDataResults[i];
                var latlong = searchMapDataResults[i]['latlong'],
                    latLngArray = latlong.split(','),
                    latitude = parseFloat(latLngArray[0]),
                    longitude = parseFloat(latLngArray[1]),
                    myLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                // addMarker(myLatLong);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: myLatLong,
                    zoom: 14
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                (function(marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                        document.getElementById('directionsDiv').innerHTML = '';
                        document.getElementById('residentInfoDiv').innerHTML = '';
                        document.getElementById('dataTitle').innerHTML = "<br><h2 class='text-center'><strong>Resident's Data</strong><br></h2>";
                        document.getElementById('residentInfoDiv').innerHTML = "<div class='row text-center'><h4 class='text-center' style='text-decoration: underline;'><strong>Information</strong></h4><div class='col-sm-6' id='resInfoTitleDist'>" + "<b>First Name: </b>" + data.name + "<br><br>" + "<b>Middle Name: </b>" + data.mname + "<br><br>" + "<b>Last Name: </b>" + data.lname + "<br><br>" + "<b>Gender: </b>" + data.gender + "<br><br>" + "<b>Birthdate: </b>" + data.bday + "<br><br>" + "<b>Age: </b>" + data.age + "<br><br>" + "<b>Citizenship: </b>" + data.citizenship + "<br><br>" + "<b>Occupation: </b>" + data.occupation + "<br><br>" + "</div><div class='col-sm-6' id='resInfoTitleDist'><b>Status: </b>" + data.status + "<br><br>" + "<b>Purok: </b>" + data.purok + "<br><br>" + "<b>Residential Address: </b>" + data.resAddress + "<br><br>" + "<b>Permanent Address: </b>" + data.perAddress + "<br><br>" + "<b>Email: </b>" + data.email + "<br><br>" + "<b>Telephone #: </b>" + data.telNum + "<br><br>" + "<b>Cellphone #: </b>" + data.cpNum + "<br><br>" + "</div></div>";
                        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                        calculateAndDisplayRoute(data.latlong);
                        document.getElementById('directionsDiv').innerHTML = "<h4 class='text-center' style='text-decoration: underline;'><strong>Location</strong><br><br></h4>";
                        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsDiv'));
                        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(myLatLong, myLatLong);

                        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                            if (bounds.contains(map.getCenter()))
                                return;
                            var c = map.getCenter(),
                                x = c.lng(),
                                y = c.lat(),
                                maxX = bounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                                maxY = bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                                minX = bounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
                                minY = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
                            if (x < minX) {
                                x = minX
                            };
                            if (x > maxX) {
                                x = maxX
                            };
                            if (y < minY) {
                                y = minY
                            };
                            if (y > maxY) {
                                y = maxY
                            };
                            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
                        });
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }

            function setMapOnAll(map) {
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                    // console.log(markers.length);
                    // console.log(markers[i]);
                }
            }

            function removeMarkers() {
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                    console.log("removed.");
                }
            }

            function clearMarkers() {
                setMapOnAll(null);
                console.log("cleared.");
            }

            function showMarkers() {
                setMapOnAll(map);
            }

            function deleteMarkers() {
                clearMarkers();
                markers = [];
                console.log("deleted.");
            }

            function calculateAndDisplayRoute(latLongDest) {
                var start = new google.maps.LatLng(7.282397, 125.683499);
                var end = latLongDest;
                directionsService.route({
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function(response, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    } else {
                        // alertify.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status + ',' + myLatLong).set('modal', false, 'movable', false);
                        $.bootstrapGrowl('<h4><strong>Error!</strong></h4> <p>Directions request failed due to ' + status + ',' + myLatLong + '!</p>', {
                            type: "danger",
                            delay: 2500,
                            width: "auto",
                            allow_dismiss: true,
                            offset: {
                                from: 'top',
                                amount: 20
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            var flightPlanCoordinates = [{
                lat: 7.292363,
                lng: 125.667018
            }, {
                lat: 7.291958,
                lng: 125.671030
            }, {
                lat: 7.292022,
                lng: 125.673777
            }, {
                lat: 7.291532,
                lng: 125.675864
            }, {
                lat: 7.292884,
                lng: 125.676464
            }, {
                lat: 7.292809,
                lng: 125.677291
            }, {
                lat: 7.292682,
                lng: 125.680069
            }, {
                lat: 7.292283,
                lng: 125.682475
            }, {
                lat: 7.291916,
                lng: 125.684653
            }, {
                lat: 7.290319,
                lng: 125.685706
            }, {
                lat: 7.290787,
                lng: 125.688089
            }, {
                lat: 7.292937,
                lng: 125.689033
            }, {
                lat: 7.294427,
                lng: 125.689951
            }, {
                lat: 7.296428,
                lng: 125.691737
            }, {
                lat: 7.295853,
                lng: 125.692123
            }, {
                lat: 7.295300,
                lng: 125.692273
            }, {
                lat: 7.293703,
                lng: 125.694247
            }, {
                lat: 7.294001,
                lng: 125.694612
            }, {
                lat: 7.294172,
                lng: 125.697123
            }, {
                lat: 7.291000,
                lng: 125.698678
            }, {
                lat: 7.289723,
                lng: 125.697091
            }, {
                lat: 7.287808,
                lng: 125.695717
            }, {
                lat: 7.285573,
                lng: 125.691866
            }, {
                lat: 7.284466,
                lng: 125.690793
            }, {
                lat: 7.282657,
                lng: 125.689763
            }, {
                lat: 7.279996,
                lng: 125.688411
            }, {
                lat: 7.278123,
                lng: 125.686930
            }, {
                lat: 7.277208,
                lng: 125.686287
            }, {
                lat: 7.276059,
                lng: 125.685600
            }, {
                lat: 7.274207,
                lng: 125.683604
            }, {
                lat: 7.274037,
                lng: 125.683175
            }, {
                lat: 7.275675,
                lng: 125.678412
            }, {
                lat: 7.275697,
                lng: 125.673975
            }, {
                lat: 7.280188,
                lng: 125.674565
            }, {
                lat: 7.280156,
                lng: 125.672009
            }, {
                lat: 7.286728,
                lng: 125.674788
            }, {
                lat: 7.287308,
                lng: 125.673302
            }, {
                lat: 7.288127,
                lng: 125.669896
            }, {
                lat: 7.287137,
                lng: 125.669834
            }, {
                lat: 7.287196,
                lng: 125.665787
            }, {
                lat: 7.288962,
                lng: 125.666312
            }, {
                lat: 7.288718,
                lng: 125.667889
            }, {
                lat: 7.290819,
                lng: 125.667830
            }, {
                lat: 7.291123,
                lng: 125.668512
            }, {
                lat: 7.289612,
                lng: 125.668116
            }, {
                lat: 7.289734,
                lng: 125.668899
            }, {
                lat: 7.290080,
                lng: 125.668830
            }, {
                lat: 7.290309,
                lng: 125.669729
            }, {
                lat: 7.290271,
                lng: 125.670128
            }, {
                lat: 7.290301,
                lng: 125.670828
            }, {
                lat: 7.291330,
                lng: 125.670852
            }, {
                lat: 7.291793,
                lng: 125.666922
            }, {
                lat: 7.291916,
                lng: 125.666885
            }, {
                lat: 7.292363,
                lng: 125.667018
            }];
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);

            var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(7.274053, 125.666105), new google.maps.LatLng(7.296828, 125.698691));

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter()))
                    return;
                var c = map.getCenter(),
                    x = c.lng(),
                    y = c.lat(),
                    maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                    maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                    minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
                    minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();
                if (x < minX) {
                    x = minX
                };
                if (x > maxX) {
                    x = maxX
                };
                if (y < minY) {
                    y = minY
                };
                if (y > maxY) {
                    y = maxY
                };
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
            });
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        $("#searchResult").html('');
        // alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
        // alertify.error('Search result empty!').dismissOthers();
        $.bootstrapGrowl("<h4><strong>Resident not found!</strong></h4> <p>Search result empty!</p>", {
            type: "warning",
            delay: 2500,
            width: "auto",
            allow_dismiss: true,
            offset: {
                from: 'top',
                amount: 20
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('directionsDiv').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('residentInfoDiv').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('dataTitle').innerHTML = "";
        // google.maps.trigger(map, 'resize');
        return;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

To remove all markers, you must first clear the markers of Google Maps instance

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null); //clear markers of instance google maps
}

markers = []; // destroy array with Markers
```

Comment: Where should i put those codes? because i apply the codes inside `removeMarker`, before and inside the `for()` loop based on the codes above. Please respond asap.

Comment: hi emo_noel10, this code you have apply in one function responsablity for clear alll markers.

Is very important have the instance the Google Maps in your context for use the function setMap(null);

Comment: Hi @Mateus Pontes, I already apply it in my code before you answer this based on the google maps docs and it works now. Thanks btw (y)