# Clearing markers on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have made a custom Google map with two sets of markers. I'm trying to write a function to clear the markers but can't get it to work.

The function:

```
function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
};
```

This works when the markers are in the lat, long format like below:

```
var locs1 = [
{lat: 51.2, lng: 0},
{lat: 52, lng: 0.3}
]
```

But when I use an array to define the markers (as below) it no longer works:

```
var locs1 = [
['Name', 51.2, 0, 'Info'],
['Name', 52, 0.3, 'Info']
];
```

How can I make the clearMarkers function work properly?

Full code can be found in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravfLkvw/1/) to help understand context.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself** that demonstrates the problem.  Neither of the `locs1` objects you posted are the array of markers, and you haven't posted the code that creates the markers array from them.

Comment: Your fiddle has a javascript error `Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined`

Comment: Sorry fella, I'm still getting used to StackOverflow. Will bear this in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable markers should be global and not declared in function.

I edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravfLkvw/4/).

```
var markers = [];

var locs1 = [
['Name', 51.2, 0, 'Info'],
['Name', 52, 0.3, 'Info']
];

var locs2 = [
['Name', 53, -1.93, ' Info'], ['Name', 51, -1.8979, 'Info']
];
```

Comment: Thank you. Just looked over the updated code in the fiddle and I think I understand, will keep fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

I'v had this problem before. You need to keep a list or array of the Markers, then iterate over them all to clear them. Simply setting a set of cordinates to null won't necessarily clear a marker that was already there, as it is a different object.

[Google Map API - Removing Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482949/google-map-api-removing-markers)