# How to remove old map markers and update new in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating an application which gets the real-time location and renders to  Google Map. After a specific time interval, I have to remove old markers and need to render the udpated markers.

Below is my code

```
function initMap(rtl_data) {
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.238162, 45.156379);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var marker = []
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        makeMarkers(rtl_data)

        function makeMarkers(rtl_data){
            // Drivers Location Markers
            deleteMarkers()
            features = []
            marker = []
            drivers_latlng = rtl_data.drivers_latest_location
            drivers_latlng.forEach(function(e){
                features.push({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(e.lat, e.lng),
                    type: e.order_id,
                    title: e.driver_id,
                    description: e.order_id ? "Ongoing order: "+e.order_id : "No order assigned."
                })
            })

            image = "/files/truck.png"
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: features[i].position,
                    map: map,
                    title: features[i].title,
                    type: features[i].type,
                    icon: image,
                    description: features[i].description
                });
                //Attach click event to the marker.
                (function (marker) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + marker.description + "</div>");
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker);
            }

            // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
            function setMapOnAll(map) {
                for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
                    marker[i].setMap(map);
                }
            }

            // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
            function clearMarkers() {
                setMapOnAll(null);
                console.log('clearMarkers')
            }

            // Shows any markers currently in the array.
            function showMarkers() {
                setMapOnAll(map);
            }

            // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
            function deleteMarkers() {
                console.log('deleteMarkers')
                clearMarkers();
                marker = [];
            }
        }

        // Fetch Realtime using time interval
        setInterval(function() {
            frappe.call({ // Simple AJAX Call which returns locations and location realated data.
                method: "get_drivers_locations",
                async: false,
                callback: function(r){
                    rtl_data = r.message
                }
            })
            makeMarkers(rtl_data)
        }, 5000);
```

I already used Method's which is used in the documentaion by Google Map.
Using ClearMarkers the old markers get cleared. But in my case it is not working.
When I run above code it displaying me both old and upadted markers.

See below screenshot which is repetating markers with updated locations.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You initialize marker as an array:

```
var marker = []
```

But later assign a Marker instance:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({...})
```

I didn't run your example, but I expect, that marker variable will contain not an array of markers, but the last created marker.

Try to do next:

1. rename marker variable to markers
2. implement addMarker function. This function should push a new marker to markers array

Comment: No you can refer the official documentation: 
(from Google)  
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: In the example, a new marker instance is created and then pushed to array markers: markers.push(marker); Please take a closer look to addMarker function.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer so it should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

After reading below thread:
[Google Map API - Removing Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482949/google-map-api-removing-markers)
I found the solution.
I created one array.

```
gmarkers = []
```

and pushed all my new markers in it.

```
gmarkers.push(marker)
```

To delete the markers I used the following function.

```
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems the answer below was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your closure bracket for the init function is wrong. If you look at the original documentation the init function is closed before the addmarker function. In your example it is closed just before the setInterval. So your setInterval probably can't even access the makeMarker function because this one is inside another function.