# script is executing after the function completes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am setting the `trackPath.setMapth(null);` that is clearing the polyline overlay on the map , it is executing at the end of the function I have added here.
Here cosole.log(see the function) is being printed first then the trackPath.setMap(null) is clearing.

```
function play(id, value) {
  clearTimeout(timerForTrack);
  trackPath.setMap(null);
  trackPath = null; // removing this line too makes the same thing
console.log("this is coming first than clearing the track");
  // some commented code
}
```

I have been working on this work 4 hours.
The issue is I need to add a new polyline after clearing that.Any ideas where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Obviously setMap does some async stuff

Comment: @mplungjan I need to add a new polyline after clearing that.

Comment: Is the setMap clearing your polyline? If so you may want to use setTimeout on the line

Comment: Perhaps look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers