# removing previous marker before adding new marker in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have below code to display marker in the place that I click on map. Its working perfectly and the thing is I want to remove the previous map marker when adding new marker. Where I should make changes to work perfectly.

```
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {

                    latLng = e.latLng;

                    console.log(e.latLng.lat());
                    console.log(e.latLng.lng());

                    image = clientURL + "/common/images/markers/red.png";
                    console.log("Marker");
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: image
                    });


                });
```

I refered many links that was not working for my case [To remove previous markers before adding new Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493509/to-remove-previous-markers-before-adding-new-markers)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add code to remove the marker from the map if it exists and has a .setMap method (assumes the existing marker is available in the current scope or is global):

```
if (marker && marker.setMap) {
    marker.setMap(null);
}
```

complete function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {

  latLng = e.latLng;

  console.log(e.latLng.lat());
  console.log(e.latLng.lng());

  image = clientURL + "/common/images/markers/red.png";
  console.log("Marker");
  // if marker exists and has a .setMap method, hide it
  if (marker && marker.setMap) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  }
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
   icon: image
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0rmaz6Lb/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(e) {

    latLng = e.latLng;

    console.log(e.latLng.lat());
    console.log(e.latLng.lng());

    console.log("Marker");
    // if marker exists and has a .setMap method, hide it
    if (marker && marker.setMap) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: +1 for checking if marker is null as well as if marker has set a non-null map. Else it won't work. This is one of the ways to make it work. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Similar to the answer you linked in your question you need to maintain a global reference to the last marker added to the map (the previous marker to be removed).

```
var map;
var previousMarker; // global variable to store previous marker
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
      // if the previousMarker exists, remove it
      if (previousMarker)
        previousMarker.setMap(null);

      latLng = e.latLng;

      console.log(e.latLng.lat());
      console.log(e.latLng.lng());

      //image = clientURL + "/common/images/markers/red.png";
      console.log("Marker");
      previousMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
    }

  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML code and add google map api key

```
<div id="map_div" style="width:100%;height:85px;"></div>
```

In javascript code

```
var add_marker = null,map = null;  //Declare vaiable

// map load 
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'),{
      zoom:10,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(11.342423,77.728165),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// first time map load set marker static
add_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:map,
      position:new google.maps.LatLng(11.342423,77.728165),
      zoom:10
});

map.addListener("click",function(e){
    if(add_marker != null) {            //already set marker to clear
       add_marker.setMap(null);
       add_marker = null;
    }

    // Dynamic to set marker based on click event
    add_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:map,
            position:new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(),e.latLng.lng()),
            zoom:10
    });
});
```