# Remove Markers from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the following Code for creating my markers:

```
<pre>
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png',
        title: value2["title"],
        zIndex: 4,
        html: value2["content"]
    });
</pre>
```

Now I want to remove all Markers from my map, that was created by

```
<pre>
    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 10);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: centerMap,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMapsPreview'), myOptions);
</pre>
```

Comment: If you want to remove more than one marker that is created that way, you need to have a unique reference to it/them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers):

I've corrected it, change clearMarkers method this way:

```
set_map(null) ---> setMap(null)

google.maps.Map.prototype.clearMarkers = function() {
    for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
        this.markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    this.markers = new Array();
};
```

Documentation has been updated to include details on the topic: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove

Comment: thank you :)
but next question: how to group the markers? i tried the script from the google documentation, but it didn't work...

Comment: you can ask a new question on so and mark this one as answered :) than youll get some more help ^^