# how remove selected marker in array from map without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my function of delete marker, my function delete marker working it delete the marker when i reload the page.

```
deleteCurrentMarker: function (marker_id) {
        //Find and remove the marker from the Array

        var self = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < self.markers.length; i++) {
            if (self.markers[i].id == marker_id) {
                //Remove the marker from Map

                self.markers[i].setMap(null);

                //Remove the marker from array.
                self.markers.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    },
```

and here it is my delete function that call on delete button.

```
 deleteSpot: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log("Self ====================================>" + JSON.stringify(self));

        if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this Spot?')) {
            $.getJSON(lighthouse.serviceURL + "Spots/DeleteSpot", {
                SPOT_GUID: Spot_Guid,
            }, function (response) {
                self.hideOndelete();
                lighthouse.googleMap.deleteCurrentMarker(self.selectedMarkerID);

            }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            });
        }

    },
```

Comment: You can refer this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2439176

Comment: `setMap(null)` basically removes the underlying marker from the map, not just the variable itself, but also the graphic entity. Are you sure your `self.markers` actually holds the list of the markers as they are drawn on the map?

Comment: +1 for what @TaoP.R. says.  Show us the code where you create your markers, and how you call your deleteCurrentMarker function.

Comment: yes Jason Estibeiro, my self.marker hold the list of markers array, but when i delete selected marker my delete function working perfectly but deleted markers not hide without page reloading even i use self.markers[i].setMap(null)

Comment: deleteSpot: function () {
            var self = this;       
            if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this Spot?')) {
                $.getJSON(lighthouse.serviceURL + "Spots/DeleteSpot", {
                    SPOT_GUID: Spot_Guid,
                }, function (response) {
                    self.hideOndelete();
                    lighthouse.googleMap.deleteCurrentMarker(self.selectedMarkerID);

                }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                });
            }
        },