# How to clear existing markers in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is how I implemented it,

The thing is that the function clearAirports, won't clear any existing markers (or fire any errors in the -google- console),

```
googleMaps: {
    map: null,
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        var $google_maps_item = $('#gmaps');
        if  ( $google_maps_item.length ) { 

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng( 39.615794, 2.998049 ),
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                rotateControl: false,
                disableDefaultUI: true
             };
             self.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmaps"), mapOptions);
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng($google_maps_item.data('lat'), $google_maps_item.data('long')),
                 map: self.map,
                 icon: {
                     path: "M27.648 -41.399q0 -3.816 -2.7 -6.516t-6.516 -2.7 -6.516 2.7 -2.7 6.516 2.7 6.516 6.516 2.7 6.516 -2.7 2.7 -6.516zm9.216 0q0 3.924 -1.188 6.444l-13.104 27.864q-0.576 1.188 -1.71 1.872t-2.43 0.684 -2.43 -0.684 -1.674 -1.872l-13.14 -27.864q-1.188 -2.52 -1.188 -6.444 0 -7.632 5.4 -13.032t13.032 -5.4 13.032 5.4 5.4 13.032z",
                     scale: 0.6,
                     strokeWeight: 0.2,
                     strokeColor: 'black',
                     strokeOpacity: 1,
                     fillColor: '#003547',
                     fillOpacity: 0.85,
                 }
             });         
             self.drawAirports();

        }
    },
    drawAirports: function () {
        var self = this;
        var markers = [];



        var $airports = $('.airport_list ul li:visible');
        var airports = [];

        console.log( 'hemos detectado ' + $airports.length + ' visibles' );

        $airports.each( function () {
            var airport = {
                'airport' : $(this).data('titulo'),
                'lat' : $(this).data('lat'),
                'long' : $(this).data('long'),
                'href' : $(this).data('href')
            }
            airports[airports.length] = airport;
        });


        var infobox = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
              (function (airport) {
                  console.log ( base_url + 'img/gmaps/marker.png' ); 
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(airport.lat, airport.long),
                      map: self.map,
                      title: airport.airport,
                      icon: base_url + 'img/gmaps/marker.png',
                      visible: true
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                      if(infobox) {
                          infobox.close();
                      }
                      infobox = new InfoBox({
                          content: '<h3>' + airport.airport + '</h3><a class="info" href=""><span>Información</span></a><a class="bags" href=""><span>Equipajes</span></a>',
                          disableAutoPan: false,
                          maxWidth: 150,
                          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-212, -150),
                          zIndex: null,
                          boxStyle: {
                              width: "280px"
                          },
                          closeBoxMargin: "0",
                          closeBoxURL: base_url + "img/gmaps/close.png",
                          infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                      });
                      infobox.open(map, this);
                      map.panTo(marker.position);
                  });

                  markers.push(marker);
              })(airports[i]);
          }
    },
    clearAirports: function () {
        google.maps.Map.prototype.clearMarkers = function() {
            if ( this.markers !== undefined && this.markers !== 'undefined' ) {
                console.log( this.markers.length + ' Markers to clear' );
                for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
                    this.markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
                this.markers = new Array();
            }               
        };

        this.map.clearMarkers();
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I took the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `markers` as a property of the `googleMaps` object, add all markers to it and then adjust the `clearAirports` function a bit:

```
googleMaps: {
    map: null,
    markers: [], //HERE
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        var $google_maps_item = $('#gmaps');
        if  ( $google_maps_item.length ) { 

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng( 39.615794, 2.998049 ),
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                rotateControl: false,
                disableDefaultUI: true
             };
             self.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmaps"), mapOptions);
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng($google_maps_item.data('lat'), $google_maps_item.data('long')),
                 map: self.map,
                 icon: {
                     path: "M27.648 -41.399q0 -3.816 -2.7 -6.516t-6.516 -2.7 -6.516 2.7 -2.7 6.516 2.7 6.516 6.516 2.7 6.516 -2.7 2.7 -6.516zm9.216 0q0 3.924 -1.188 6.444l-13.104 27.864q-0.576 1.188 -1.71 1.872t-2.43 0.684 -2.43 -0.684 -1.674 -1.872l-13.14 -27.864q-1.188 -2.52 -1.188 -6.444 0 -7.632 5.4 -13.032t13.032 -5.4 13.032 5.4 5.4 13.032z",
                     scale: 0.6,
                     strokeWeight: 0.2,
                     strokeColor: 'black',
                     strokeOpacity: 1,
                     fillColor: '#003547',
                     fillOpacity: 0.85,
                 }
             });   
             self.markers.push(marker); //HERE: remove if you don't want to add the first marker to the array      
             self.drawAirports();

        }
    },
    drawAirports: function () {
        var self = this;



        var $airports = $('.airport_list ul li:visible');
        var airports = [];

        console.log( 'hemos detectado ' + $airports.length + ' visibles' );

        $airports.each( function () {
            var airport = {
                'airport' : $(this).data('titulo'),
                'lat' : $(this).data('lat'),
                'long' : $(this).data('long'),
                'href' : $(this).data('href')
            }
            airports[airports.length] = airport;
        });


        var infobox = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
              (function (airport) {
                  console.log ( base_url + 'img/gmaps/marker.png' ); 
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(airport.lat, airport.long),
                      map: self.map,
                      title: airport.airport,
                      icon: base_url + 'img/gmaps/marker.png',
                      visible: true
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                      if(infobox) {
                          infobox.close();
                      }
                      infobox = new InfoBox({
                          content: '<h3>' + airport.airport + '</h3><a class="info" href=""><span>Información</span></a><a class="bags" href=""><span>Equipajes</span></a>',
                          disableAutoPan: false,
                          maxWidth: 150,
                          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-212, -150),
                          zIndex: null,
                          boxStyle: {
                              width: "280px"
                          },
                          closeBoxMargin: "0",
                          closeBoxURL: base_url + "img/gmaps/close.png",
                          infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                      });
                      infobox.open(map, this);
                      map.panTo(marker.position);
                  });

                  self.markers.push(marker); //HERE
              })(airports[i]);
          }
    },
    clearAirports: function () { //We don't need to define google.maps.Map.prototype.clearMarkers, just clear them right here
        console.log( this.markers.length + ' Markers to clear' );
        for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
              this.markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        this.markers = new Array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Remove Markers</title>
        <style>
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          #floating-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 25%;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="floating-panel">
          <input onclick="clearMarkers();" type=button value="Hide Markers">
          <input onclick="showMarkers();" type=button value="Show All Markers">
          <input onclick="deleteMarkers();" type=button value="Delete Markers">
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <p>Click on the map to add markers.</p>
        <script>

          // In the following example, markers appear when the user clicks on the map.
          // The markers are stored in an array.
          // The user can then click an option to hide, show or delete the markers.
          var map;
          var markers = [];

          function initMap() {
            var haightAshbury = {lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446};

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 12,
              center: haightAshbury,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            });

            // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
            map.addListener('click', function(event) {
              addMarker(event.latLng);
            });

            // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
            addMarker(haightAshbury);
          }

          // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
          function addMarker(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: location,
              map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
          }

          // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
          function setMapOnAll(map) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              markers[i].setMap(map);
            }
          }

          // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
          function clearMarkers() {
            setMapOnAll(null);
          }

          // Shows any markers currently in the array.
          function showMarkers() {
            setMapOnAll(map);
          }

          // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
          function deleteMarkers() {
            clearMarkers();
            markers = [];
          }
        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Fix link please

Answer (score 0):

Declare the markers array in a window  visible area .. so you can iterate and on this array for set null the realetd map ..

```
  // move this outside the  drawAirpots function 
  var markers = [];
```

the iterate on   for

```
  for ( i = 0;  i< markers.length; i++) {

    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand, how about the this.marker.setMap(null ) ? it fires: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" right now that I moved markers outside the drawArports func